# Using project reactor mergeWith() operator in order to achieve "if/elseif/else" branching logic

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am trying to use **project reactor** `mergeWith` operator in order to achieve a `if/elseif/else` branching logic as described here: [RxJS, where is the If-Else Operator](https://rangle.io/blog/rxjs-where-is-the-if-else-operator/).

The provided samples are written in RxJS but the underlying idea remains the same.

Basically the idea is to use the `filter` operator on 3 `monos/publishers` (therefore with 3 different predicates) and merge the 3 `monos` as follows (here they are RxJS `Observables` of course):

```
const somethings$ = source$
  .filter(isSomething)
  .do(something);

const betterThings$ = source$
  .filter(isBetterThings)
  .do(betterThings);

const defaultThings$ = source$
  .filter((val) => !isSomething(val) && !isBetterThings(val))
  .do(defaultThing);

// merge them together
const onlyTheRightThings$ = somethings$
  .merge(
    betterThings$,
    defaultThings$,
  )
  .do(correctThings);
```

I have copied and pasted the relevant sample from the above article.

Consider that `something$`, `betterThings$` and `defaultThings$` are our monos `isSomething` & `isBetterThings` are the predicates.

Now here are my 3 real `monos/publishers` (written in java):

```
private Mono<ServerResponse> validateUser(User user) {
    return Mono.just(new BeanPropertyBindingResult(user, User.class.getName()))
        .doOnNext(err -> userValidator.validate(user, err))
        .filter(AbstractBindingResult::hasErrors)
        .flatMap(err ->
            status(BAD_REQUEST)
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(err.getAllErrors()))
        );
}

private Mono<ServerResponse> validateEmailNotExists(User user) {
    return userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail())
        .flatMap(existingUser ->
            status(BAD_REQUEST)
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject("User already exists."))
        );
}

private Mono<ServerResponse> saveUser(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user)
        .flatMap(newUser -> status(CREATED)
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(newUser))
        );
}
```

Here is the top level method that needs to merge the three `publishers`:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> signUpUser(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    return serverRequest.bodyToMono(User.class)
        .mergeWith(...)

}
```

I am not sure how to use the `mergeWith()` operator... I have tried the `Mono.when()` static operator which takes several publishers (good for me) but returns a `Mono<void>` (bad for me).

Can anyone please help?

*P.S. I am sure you will excuse the mix between RxJS (js) and Reactor code (java). I meant to use my knowledge from RxJS in order to achieve a similar goal in my Reactor app.* :-)

**edit 1**: I have tried this:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> signUpUser(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    return serverRequest
        .bodyToMono(User.class)
        .flatMap(user -> validateUser(user).or(validateEmailNotExists(user)).or(saveUser(user))).single();
}
```

But I get this error: `NoSuchElementException: Source was empty`

**edit 2**: Same with (notice the parenthesis):

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> signUpUser(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    return serverRequest
        .bodyToMono(User.class)
        .flatMap(user -> validateUser(user).or(validateEmailNotExists(user)).or(saveUser(user)).single());
}
```

**edit 3**: Same error with a `Mono<User>`:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> signUpUser(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    Mono<User> userMono = serverRequest.bodyToMono(User.class);
    return validateUser(userMono)
        .or(validateEmailNotExists(userMono))
        .or(saveUser(userMono))
        .single();
}
```

**edit 4**: I can confirm that at least one of the three monos will always emit. It is when I use the `or()` operator that something goes wrong...

If I use this, all my tests pass:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> signUpUser(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    return serverRequest.bodyToMono(User.class)
        .flatMap(user -> Flux.concat(validateUser(user), validateEmailNotExists(user), saveUser(user)).next().single());
}
```

I have used the `concat()` operator here to preserve the order of operations.

Do you know what I am getting wrong with the `or()` operator?

**edit 5**: I have tried with the `cache()` operator as follows to no avail:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> signUpUser(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    return serverRequest
        .bodyToMono(User.class)
        .cache()
        .flatMap(user -> validateUser(user)
            .or(validateEmailNotExists(user))
            .or(saveUser(user))
            .single()
        );
}
```

Comment: The use of the `or()` operator is wrong here as it takes the first publisher that emits a result and this is not the desired effect here. See this reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57826425/536299 for more information.

Answer (score 5):

Your current code sample implies that your 3 methods returning `Mono<ServerResponse>` should be taking a `Mono<User>` rather than a `User`, so you may need to alter something there.

However, I digress - that doesn't seem to be the main question here.

From what I understand of the pattern described in that link, you're creating 3 separate `Mono` objects, only one of which will ever return a result - and you need a `Mono` of whichever one of your original 3 `Mono` objects returns.

In that case, I'd recommend something like the following:

```
Mono<ServerResult> result = Flux.merge(validateUser(user), validateEmailNotExists(user), saveUser(user)).next().single();
```

Breaking it down:

- The static `Flux.merge()` method takes your 3 `Mono` objects and merges them into a `Flux`;
- `next()` returns the first available result as a `Mono`;
- `single()` will ensure that the `Mono` emits a value, as oppose to nothing at all, and throw an exception otherwise. (Optional, but just a bit of a safety net.)

You could also just chain `Mono.or()` like so:

```
Mono<ServerResult> result = validateUser(user).or(validateEmailNotExists(user)).or(saveUser(user)).single();
```

The advantages to this approach are:

- It's arguably more readable in some cases;
- If it's possible that you'll have more than one `Mono` in your chain return a result, this allows you to set an order of precedence for which one is chosen (as oppose to the above example where you'll just get whatever `Mono` emitted a value first.)

The disadvantage is potentially one of performance. If `saveUser()` returns a value first in the above code, then you still have to wait for the other two `Mono` objects to complete before your combined `Mono` will complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael! Can you confirm whether user is a `User` or `Mono<User>` in the following code: `Mono<ServerResult> result = validateUser(user).or(validateEmailNotExists(user))....` ?

Comment: Also if user is a `User` is the only solution to `flatMap`?

Comment: @balteo It entirely depends on whether your methods there take a `Mono<User>` or a `User`. As for `flatMap` - that's equivalent to `map`, apart from it returns the value from another publisher rather than just returning the value verbatim.

Comment: Thanks for that. What about the `NoSuchElementException: Source was empty` error I mention above?

Comment: That means that none of your 3 original `Mono` objects returned any result. I'd suggest subscribing to the one that you think should return a result in that scenario, and work out why it's not.

Comment: I have edited my post (see **edit 4**). Any idea what I am getting wrong with my usage of the `or()` operator?

Comment: @balteo Ah sorry, my mistake - should have added that. Try calling `cache()` on the `Mono` like Mono<User> userMono = serverRequest.bodyToMono(User.class).cache();